# Руководство по CallableStatement

Tags: jdbc, java, mysql

подскажите нормальное руководство где можно почитать про хранимые процедуры, как их создавать и вызывать. А то у меня возникла проблема при создании их. [вот здесь](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx) рассказано как создавать хранимую процедуру. Прописываю это в `MySQL Workbench` и всё нормально - она создается, но когда я прописываю эту команду в объект `Statement` драйвера `JDBC` , команда не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) нужен для вызова хранимой поцедуры, а не для ее создания.
Пример использвания есть в [Java Tutorial: JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html).

Comment: я знаю для чего нужен callablestatement. но я хочу знать как и создавать их с помощью statement и вызывать c помощью callablestatement. проблема в том что я не смог создать хранимую процедуру с помощью объекта statement.

Comment: @argamidon Значит формулируйте вопрос корректно, т.к. фраза "но когда я прописываю эту команду в объект Statement драйвера JDBC , команда не работает" намекает на то, что вы пытаетесь создать процедуру. В люьом случае, ответы на ваш вопрос находится по ссылке, приведенной мной в ответе.

Comment: String createString = "create procedure SHOW_SUPPLIERS()"
                + "begin "
                + "select * from main_data.table1;"
                + "end";
Этот statement при запуске  в java работает. процедура создается. НО когда я пытаюсь в MYSQL workbench прописать эту же самую процедуру, workbench ругается - syntax error. [скриншот][1]. почему так? один и тотже код ведь!


  [1]: http://i058.radikal.ru/1407/1d/cb5ae9b938a1.jpg